# How do I pass multiple parameters in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, syntax, parameters, methods

I have read several of the post about Objective-C method syntax but I guess I don't understand multiple names for a method.

I'm trying to create a method called `getBusStops` with `NSString` and `NSTimeInterval` parameters and a return type of `NSMutableArray`. This is how I have constructed the method but it obviously gets errors at runtime:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getBusStops:(NSString *)busStop
                                (NSTimeInterval *)timeInterval;
```

I saw another example with a method:

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
            numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

I don't understand why this method has a method name for each parameter. Should I do the same with something like:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getBusStops:(NSString *)busStop
                        forTime:(NSTimeInterval *)timeInterval
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Objective-C doesn't have named parameters, so everything on the left side of a colon is part of the method name. For example,

```
getBusStops: forTime:
```

is the name of the method. The name is broken up so it can be more descriptive. You could simply name your method

```
getBusStops: :
```

but that doesn't tell you much about the second parameter.

Comment: That's so ugly (excuse me) to me who have been using c# for 6 years and swift 1+ year. I really could not get method signature and had to google it

Answer (score 169):

You need to delimit each parameter name with a ":" at the very least. Technically the name is optional, but it is recommended for readability. So you could write:

```
- (NSMutableArray*)getBusStops:(NSString*)busStop :(NSTimeInterval*)timeInterval;
```

or what you suggested:

```
- (NSMutableArray*)getBusStops:(NSString*)busStop forTime:(NSTimeInterval*)timeInterval;
```

Comment: +1: Objective-C function arguments are indeed positional, not named, so the label is optional and for human consumption.

Comment: not sure why "forTime" is preferred in the signature,  "timeInterval" can be used as the 2nd parameter in the function, right?

Comment: @galactica - Sure, the name can be whatever makes the most sense to you. This example uses the OP's terminology for consistency.

Comment: Still not sure what is `forTime` used for?

Comment: `forTime` makes calling the method read more like an English sentence. E.g., `[array getBusStops:... forTime:...];`

Answer (score 74):

Yes; the Objective-C method syntax is like this for a couple of reasons; one of these is so that it is clear what the parameters you are specifying are. For example, if you are adding an object to an `NSMutableArray` at a certain index, you would do it using the method:

```
- (void)insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

This method is called `insertObject:atIndex:` and it is clear that an object is being inserted at a specified index.

In practice, adding a string "Hello, World!" at index 5 of an `NSMutableArray` called `array` would be called as follows:

```
NSString *obj = @"Hello, World!";
int index = 5;

[array insertObject:obj atIndex:index];
```

This also reduces ambiguity between the order of the method parameters, ensuring that you pass the object parameter first, *then* the index parameter. This becomes more useful when using functions that take a large number of arguments, and reduces error in passing the arguments.

Furthermore, the method naming convention is such because Objective-C doesn't support overloading; however, if you want to write a method that does the same job, but takes different data-types, this can be accomplished; take, for instance, the `NSNumber` class; this has several object creation methods, including:

- `+ (id)numberWithBool:(BOOL)value;`
- `+ (id)numberWithFloat:(float)value;`
- `+ (id)numberWithDouble:(double)value;`

In a language such as C++, you would simply overload the number method to allow different data types to be passed as the argument; however, in Objective-C, this syntax allows several different variants of the same function to be implemented, by changing the name of the method for each variant of the function.

Comment: are the parameter names required during method call (message send) if the function name includes parameter names ?

Answer (score 24):

The text before each parameter is **part** of the method name.  From your example, the name of the method is actually

```
-getBusStops:forTime:
```

Each : represents an argument.  In a method call, the method name is split at the :s and arguments appear after the :s. e.g.

```
[getBusStops: arg1 forTime: arg2]
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add the name of the method.

Answer (score 17):

for create method:

```
-(void)mymethods:(NSString *)aCont withsecond:(NSString *)a-second {
//method definition...
}
```

for call the method:

```
[mymethods:self.contoCorrente withsecond:self.asecond];
```

Answer (score -2):

```
(int) add: (int) numberOne plus: (int) numberTwo ;
(returnType) functionPrimaryName : (returnTypeOfArgumentOne) argumentName functionSecondaryNa
```

me:

```
(returnTypeOfSecontArgument) secondArgumentName ;
```

as in other languages we use following syntax
void `add(int one, int second)`
but way of assigning arguments in `OBJ_c` is different as described above