# Newbie question -multiple parameters

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to implement a private method which takes an NSMutableDictionary and a Player object as its parameters. As it is a private method, the only place that it exists is in the ".m" file.

It is declared as

```
-(void) incrementScore: (NSMutableDictionary*) scoreboard  forPlayer: ( Player* ) player {
```

and I call it as follows :

```
      [ self incrementScore:deuceScore forPlayer:p];
```

However,it won't compile - I get

> may not response to message -incrementScore:forplayer

I'm not sure where my error lies - do I need to declare the method in the ".h" file, or elsewhere in the ".m" file, or have I just got the syntax completely wrong?

Comment: You can easily find your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722651/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler needs to find a declaration for your method somewhere before you use it. This be done in three way:

1. Declare the method in the (public) `@interface` for the class in its `.h` file .
2. Declare the method in a [class extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2) (a semi-private `@interface`, usually at the top of the `.m` files).
3. Define the method somewhere in the `@implementation` before your first use of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a warning not a compile error... (if you changed preferences to treat all warnings like error it'll be a compile error).

Probably the line calling the method is above (in the .m file) the declaration method. Move the method just below @implementation directive, or above the method with the calling line. The warning/error should disapper.