# Does using parameters in methods change anything about the method's function?

Tags: objective-c, methods, parameters, return-type

I've tried searching google and this site regarding my question but found no answer.

I'm a beginner with Obj-C and would like this question answered.

What is the benefit of using parameters in my methods.

for example..

```
 -(id)initWithName:(NSString *)newName atFrequency:(double)newFreq { 
self = [super init]; 
if (self != nil) {
name = newName; 
frequency = newFrequency;
} 
return self;
}
```

versus

```
 -(void)myMethod {
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
name = newName;
frequency = newFrequency;
}
return self;
}
```

I understand that the -(void) means the method has no return type, and the -(id) means that the first method has 'id' as a return type, and 'id' is generic....

can anyone help explain? I hope my question makes sense, thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are inputs to a method, just like function/method parameters in any language. In your second example, on the line `frequency = newFrequency;`, where is `newFrequency` supposed to come from?

In other languages, where you might have something like

```
void initWithName(string newName, double newFreq);
```

In Obj-C the equivalent is

```
- (void)initWithName:(NSString *)newName atFrequency:(double)newFreq;
```

The difference is that in Obj-C, **there is an extra piece of the method name for each parameter** (like the `atFrequency`) — in this case, the method name is `initWithName:atFrequency:`, not just `initWithName:`.

(This is actually optional, you only have to have a `:` for each parameter. Technically `initWithName::` is still a valid method name, but that's not considered good practice in Obj-C.)

See also:

- [How do I pass multiple parameters in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722651/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-in-objective-c)
- [Is there a language out there in which parameters are placed inside method name?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102906/is-there-a-language-out-there-in-which-parameters-are-placed-inside-method-name)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply jtbandes..

but what I'm trying to understand is , is there a benefit to using parameters? Couldn't I just write a method that does the same thing without the parameters in my method name?

Comment: @Instafal How would you pass any input to such a method?

Comment: I think I just figured it out...

when I use parameters in my method it only helps explain what my method does when I'm reading it.. 

whereas if I don't use parameters and my method returns void, I'd have to take an extra step and send my object the method. 

With parameters and when a function returns 'id' I can just save my self the step by doing  "MyClass *object = [[MyClass alloc]initWith:parameter1:parameter2];