# How to pass 2 parameters with a self method Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c

This is probably a noobish question that has been answered before, but I can't seem to find a solution online (Google is not being friendly). My question is, relating to Cocos2d, how would I pass 2 parameters using a self method.
An Example of my Code

```
-(void)Random {
    [self AiCharacter:theEvilOne];
    [self AiCharacter:theEvilTwo];
}

-(void)AiCharacter(CCSprite*)EvilCharacter {
    //stuff
}
```

But I want to do something like the following

```
-(void)Random {
    num = 1
    [self AiCharacter:theEvilOne, Num];
    num = 2
    [self AiCharacter:theEvilTwo, Num];
}

 -(void)AiCharacter:(CCSprite*)EvilCharacter (NSInteger*)num { //This line is what seems to be incorrectly formatted/syntactically incorrect. 
    //stuff
}
```

To give you some more info into what I am doing is that I have an multi-dimensional array of values relating to my separate AI Characters and have the num value to differentiate the rows pertaining to each sprite.

Comment: Do you come from a C# background? Objective C naming convention is lower camel case for method names.

Comment: Tibor Udvari thanks for the reply, I have only been programming (as in no experience in any language) for less than 2 weeks, I am a school student doing this for a major project. Thanks for the information I'll try use it in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
-(void)Random {
   num = 1
   [self AiCharacter:theEvilOne: Num];
   num = 2
   [self AiCharacter:theEvilTwo: Num];
 }

-(void)AiCharacter:(CCSprite*)EvilCharacter :  (NSInteger*)num {
  //This line is what seems to be incorrectly formatted/syntactically incorrect.
  //stuff
 }
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly :) thanks accepted yours because it was the quickest and it worked.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to downvote, someone else must have done that, sorry about that

Comment: @Joge Did you mean "num" and not "Num" for the second argument?

Comment: My means we need to pass first argument and after than need to pass second arguments.

Comment: @FuzzyBunnySlippers I understand what you are saying and I used num when I implemented his solution and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The ":" defines a parameter in a method signature. This is how to write it :

```
-(void)AiCharacter:(CCSprite*)EvilCharacter num:(NSInteger*)num {
}
```

You can check this post for more information [How do I pass multiple parameters in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722651/how-do-i-pass-multiple-parameters-in-objective-c)

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). This got me in the right direction but I was confused with how to actually call the method with self still. I would upvote but don't have enough rep

Answer (score 0):

See the method calling way carefully especially the colons and the parameters... or else you will encounter a crash

```
               -(void)Random {
                    num = 1
                   [self AiCharacter:theEvilOne number:num];
                   num = 2
                   [self AiCharacter:theEvilTwo number:num];
                }

          -(void)AiCharacter:(CCSprite*)EvilCharacter number:(NSInteger)num {

                }
```

Comment: I accepted the other guys because he answered first and it worked just as well

Answer (score -1):

```
 Try this

-(void)Random {

CGPoint point=ccp(1.0,2.0);
[self AiCharacter:theEvilOne: point];

}

-(void)AiCharacter:(CCSprite*)EvilCharacter :(CGPoint)point { 

float x=point.x;
float y=point.y;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I accepted the other guy as the best answer because his solution was using the same variables as mine and he answered quicker. Thanks anyway