# NSInvalidArgumentException while saving image to photoalbums

Tags: ios, objective-c

im trying to download an image file and save it to phot albums as following

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"Downloading Started");
        NSString *urlToDownload = @"http://wallpapercave.com/wp/66iglE0.jpg";
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToDownload];

        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        if ( urlData )
        {
            NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.jpg"];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
                NSLog(@"File Saved !");
                NSData *retrievedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
               ;


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum( [UIImage imageWithData:retrievedData],
                                                   self,
                                                   @selector(done),
                                                   NULL);                });
            });
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"Failed");
            });
        }

    });
```

But im getting the following error,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSInvocation
>   setArgument:atIndex:]: index (2) out of bounds [-1, 1]'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1816751b8 0x1800ac55c 0x18156db24 0x18c4ff9b0 0x18c500570 0x18bdd8ddc 0x100a45258 0x100a45218
>   0x100a4a280 0x181622810 0x1816203fc 0x18154e2b8 0x183002198
>   0x1875957fc 0x187590534 0x1000bcac8 0x1805315b8) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

How will i be able to sort this out?

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the issue? `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()` one? What's the code of `-done`?

Comment: @Hara Hara Mahadevaki: Add an exception breakpoint to get the exact line where the crash is taking place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm answering because no one tells you exactly WHY, and they use uppercase with no reason in the signature.

From the doc of [`void UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum?language=objc)

> **completionSelector**
> The method selector of the completionTarget object
> to call. This optional method should conform to the following
> signature:
>
> ```
> - (void)image:(UIImage *)image
>     didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
>                  contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo;
> ```

So you can't use `@selector(done)` because it's not compliant, and that's why your code crash.

Also, please do not use uppercase wherever you want for the signature of the method like the other answers:
`-(void)done:(UIImage *)image Error:(NSError *)error Context:(void*)context` should be named at least `-(void)done:(UIImage *)image error:(NSError *)error context:(void*)context`.
And it may be better to explicit the introduction of the parameters.

Comment: swift version of the answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387525/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-selector-syntax-issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `done` function as below

```
-(void)done:(UIImage *)image Error:(NSError *)error Context:(void*)context{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working in Swift 5.3.2:

```swift
@objc func done(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError: NSError, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer?) {
    // TODO
}
```

Not really sure if the type of `contextInfo` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"Downloading Started");
    NSString *urlToDownload = @"http://wallpapercave.com/wp/66iglE0.jpg";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToDownload];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if ( urlData )
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum( [UIImage imageWithData:urlData],
                                               self,
                                               @selector(done),
                                               NULL);               
 });
    } else {
         NSLog(@"Failed");
    }
});
```

Try this code save data directly on gallary because you are getting image data no need to save locally and retry that again

Comment: Please explain where was the mistake along with your answer.

Comment: add some description

Answer (score 0):

hi @Hara Hara Mahadevaki: the error is coming of the selector you add while saving the image can you try this

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithData:retrievedData], self, @selector(saveImage:Error:Context:), nil);
```

method call after completion

```
- (void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image Error:(NSError *)error Context:(void*)context {
    if (error) {
        // error comes
    } else {
        // image successfully save
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, Happy Coding

Comment: swift version. And also, `Context` is unavailabe in swift ?